# Intensity along null geodesic

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, computational-physics, geodesics

Let $\mathcal P$ be a bundle of light with a continous spectrum of frequencies $\nu$ emitting from $x^\mu$ in a static spacetime $g_{\mu\nu}$ (e.g. kerr-schild) in the direction $n^\mu = \frac{p^\mu}{\nu}$. I follow $\mathcal P$ along the null geodesic and want to calculate its intensity $I$ along the way.
In flat spacetime the intensity remains constant, while in a general spacetime due to redshift the intensity will change.

Let $f = I_\nu/\nu^3$ be the distribution function of our light bunddle $\mathcal P$ and $I_\nu$ the spicific intensity. Due to the absence of collisions the Boltzmann-equation can be written as (alternatively just interpret the specific intensity $I_\nu/\nu^3$ as a Lorentz scalar),

\begin{align}
    0&= \frac{df}{d\lambda} = \frac{d(I_\nu/\nu^3)}{d\lambda}
      = \frac{dt}{d\lambda}\frac{d(I_\nu/\nu^3)}{dt}
      = \nu\Big(\frac{1}{\nu^3}\frac{dI_\nu}{dt} + I_\nu\frac{d\nu^{-3}}{dt}\Big)\\
    \frac{d\nu^{-3}}{dt} &= -\frac{3}{\nu^4}\frac{d\nu}{dt}
      = -\frac{3}{\nu^4}\frac{d\lambda}{dt}\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda} \stackrel{\nu=p^0}{=}
         \frac{3}{\nu^5}\Gamma^0_{\alpha\beta} p^\alpha p^\beta
      =  \frac{3}{\nu^3}\Gamma^0_{\alpha\beta} n^\alpha n^\beta\\
    \Rightarrow 0
     &= \nu\Big(\frac{1}{\nu^3}\frac{dI_\nu}{dt}
      + \frac{3I_\nu}{\nu^3}\Gamma^0_{\alpha\beta} n^\alpha n^\beta\Big).
\end{align}

Where I have used $dt/d\lambda = \nu$ twice and the geodesic equation $\frac{dp^\mu}{d\lambda} + \Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta} p^\alpha p^\beta = 0$.
Next I multiply by $\nu^2$ and integrate over $\int_0^\infty..d\nu$. This 'gray approximation' averages over all frequencies and gives us the total intensity $I=\int_0^\infty I_\nu d\nu$.

\begin{align}
    \frac{dI}{dt} &= - 3I\Gamma^0_{\alpha\beta} n^\alpha n^\beta \\
    \Rightarrow
    I(t+\Delta t) &\approx I(t) - 3I(t)\Gamma^0_{\alpha\beta} n^\alpha n^\beta \Delta t
\end{align}

I use this equation to integrate the starting intensity  to get the intensity of the photon bundle $\mathcal P$ along the null geodesic. The geodesic equations themselves I also solve in terms of coordinate time $t$,

\begin{align}
    \frac{dx^k}{dt} &= n^k,\\
    \frac{dn^k}{dt} &= -\partial_\delta g_{\alpha\beta} n^\beta
    (n^\delta A^{k\alpha} - \frac{1}{2}n^\alpha A^{k\delta}),
    \qquad A^{k\delta} := g^{k\delta} - g^{0\delta}n^k
\end{align}

To test if everything is correct I compared my numerical result to an analytical result in cartesian Kerr-Schild coordinates with $a=0$. Due to $f= I_\nu/\nu^3$ being Lorentz-invariant the total intensity $I$ must transform as,

\begin{align}
    \frac{I_e}{\nu^4_e} &= \frac{I_r}{\nu^4_r}\\
    \Rightarrow I_r &= I_e / s^4,\qquad s = z+1 = \frac{\nu_e}{\nu_r}
    = \sqrt{\frac{g_{tt}(x^\mu_r)}{g_{tt}(x^\mu_e)}}
\end{align}

where $I_e$ ist short for the emitted intensity and $I_r$ for the received intensity.
The picture below shows the final result. A pohoton bundle with initial intensity $I_0=100$ is emittet at $x^\mu = (0,3,0,0)$ in the direction $n^\mu = (1,1,0,0)$ (which is then normalized with the metric to give a proper null vector).

[image: Numerical(num) vs analytical(ana) result]

The blue line (I num) is the numerical result and the orange line (I ana) the analytical one.
Obviously something went wrong. Can you see any mistake in my calculations or logical reasoning?

**Background:**

I need to be able to do this for a LBM based radiation transport equation solver in general spacetimes.